# How do I apply headings to list items in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to apply the style `"NORMAL"` to a list item. While in the generated Google doc the list item's style is set to `"NORMAL"`, the formatting is not the one set in the document's `"NORMAL"` style. Whereas, when I apply the style `"NORMAL"` to a paragraph, it works perfectly.

I've tried to use `setHeading()` and `setAttributes()`.

```
var print = body.appendListItem(paragraph).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);
print.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
```

The style is rightly set but without the actual formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I create a style and then apply that style in one of my scripts and ti works fine

```
var replaceStyle = {};
replaceStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] = true;
replaceStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#afeeee";
replaceStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.STRIKETHROUGH] = false;
```

And then later in the document

`child.setAttributes(removeStyle);`

this seems to work just fine for list items. Would that work or you?

Comment: Thanks, I will pull out the attributes of the document's Normal style first and try that (I forgot to say that the script duplicates a styled template document).